# VB.net calculate thumbnail coordinates to save crop from original image

Tags: vb.net

I have a preview picture where I can zoom and drag an image, what I need is to save the same portion of image shown in the preview picturebox but to real image (1274x2105 px) cropped.

[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik04Q.jpg)

When save the preview picture box (BtnSavePreview), the image its correct, but not work for the original image BtnSaveCrop, Im using the next code.

```
Private Sub BtnSavePreview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSavePreview.Click

    Dim img As New Bitmap(PnlPan.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, PnlPan.Height - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    gr.DrawImage(PicPreview.Image, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size), New Rectangle(-PnlPan.AutoScrollPosition.X, -PnlPan.AutoScrollPosition.Y, img.Width, img.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    img.Save("C:\_workingFILES\image_preview_crop.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

End Sub

Private Sub BtnSaveCrop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveCrop.Click
    Dim CropRect As New Rectangle(-PnlPan.AutoScrollPosition.X, -PnlPan.AutoScrollPosition.Y, ImgZoomPan.Width, ImgZoomPan.Height)


    Dim Left As Integer = CropRect.Left * (ImgOrig.Width / ImgZoomPan.Width)
    Dim Top As Integer = CropRect.Top * (ImgOrig.Height / ImgZoomPan.Height)
    Dim Right As Integer = CropRect.Right * (ImgOrig.Width / ImgZoomPan.Width)
    Dim Bottom As Integer = CropRect.Bottom * (ImgOrig.Height / ImgZoomPan.Height)

    Dim img As New Bitmap(Right - Left, Bottom - Top)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    gr.DrawImage(ImgOrig, New Rectangle(0, 0, Right - Left, Bottom - Top), New Rectangle(Right, Bottom, img.Width, img.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    img.Save("C:\_workingFILES\image_crop.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: There's a custom class with all the methods needed to perform this kind of operations here: [Translate Rectangle Position in Zoom Mode Picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802043/7444103). C# code, translatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fixes working now:

```
Private Sub BtnSaveCrop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveCrop.Click

    Dim CropRect As New Rectangle(-PnlPan.AutoScrollPosition.X, -PnlPan.AutoScrollPosition.Y, PnlPan.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, PnlPan.Height - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight)

    Dim Left As Integer = CropRect.Left * (ImgOrig.Width / PicPreview.Width)
    Dim Top As Integer = CropRect.Top * (ImgOrig.Height / PicPreview.Height)
    Dim Right As Integer = CropRect.Right * (ImgOrig.Width / PicPreview.Width)
    Dim Bottom As Integer = CropRect.Bottom * (ImgOrig.Height / PicPreview.Height)


    Dim cropArea As New Rectangle(Left, Top, Right, Bottom)

    Dim img As New Bitmap(Right - Left, Bottom - Top)
    Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    gr.DrawImage(ImgOrig, New Rectangle(0, 0, cropArea.Width, cropArea.Height), cropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    img.Save("C:\_workingFILES\image_crop.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)


End Sub
```

thanks