# Simulate image click using the picture box in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picture box in a windows forms project, the picture box has the size property set to Stretch. I figured that clicking on a point on the picture box would mirror a click on the same exact co-ordinate on the image nested inside that picture box, but when I click on a point on the picture box, the calculation does not accurately mirror that point on the image. I capture the point clicked using the picture box's MouseClick event handler, then I perform calculations on point to draw over on the image and then I draw a circle over that point on the original image. The point drawn on the image is a little to the left and top of the actual position I clicked on the picture box. I need to get the point right so my user can click on any section of the image and add a watermark. Here is my code

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
  //calculate the point on the image
  var imageX = e.X *(pictureBox1.Image.Width/pictureBox1.Width);
  var imageY = e.Y * (pictureBox1.Image.Height/pictureBox1.Height);
  var point = new Point(imageX, imageY);
 //draw a circle on that point
  var circle = new CircleF(point, 5);
  var path = paths[index];
  var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(path);
  image.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Red),5);
  pictureBox1.Image = ToBitmap(image);
}
```

The circle is draw some distance to the left and some distance to the top of the actual position I clicked on the picture box. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you doing inside `image.Draw` method ? Are you using GDI+ to draw the circle ?

Comment: @Madhatter, I am using emgu Cv. Image<Bgr , byte> is an emgu cv type

Comment: You might experience inaccuracy cause you are manipulating integers during your point interpolation. Is that better with `var imageX = e.X *(1.0f * pictureBox1.Image.Width/pictureBox1.Width);` ?

Comment: ... Or you can remove parenthesis and do `var imageX = e.X * pictureBox1.Image.Width/pictureBox1.Width;`

Comment: @Madhatter, you are a genius. I did the same for imageY and it worked.  Thanks. Your the best

Comment: You know you can use [GDI to draw on images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-fromimage)? No need to reload the image from disk, or to introduce an emguCV dependency.

Comment: [Translate Rectangle Position in a Picturebox in Zoom Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53800328/7444103)

Comment: @JonasH, Emgu CV needs me to reload the image from disk every time I perform an action. For this problem, it was a math issue in the point interpolation. Now it's working fine