# Detect if the Control was Moved inside the picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.drawing

I have added a custom control to picturebox.I need to check if the control has been moved.
Currently i use pictureboxmousemove event,which obviously has some issues.
I have tried adding the `mousemouse` event to the control as well.It does not seem to work.How can i sort this issue?

```
 pictureBox5.Controls.Clear();
 var c = new FrameControl();
 c.Size = obj.Size;
 c.Location = obj.Location;
 pictureBox5.Controls.Add(c);
```

UPDATE:
I have tried overriding the `mousemove` event of the Frame Control but it does not seem to work.

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
 base.OnMouseMove(e);
//Debugger does not hit breakpoint
  }
```

Comment: "...It does not seem to work..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: What makes the control move? By default it wont move, thus your code allows and makes it move. What about dispatching an event from there?

Comment: @JohnB Please see update.

Comment: OnMouseMove is raised when the Mouse Pointer move inside a Control's bounds. This allows to move the Control, by updating the Control's position using the relative `e.Location` values. Since this Control movement is constrained by the *Container's* bounds, you can calculate the movents using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316286/dont-move-the-labels-outside-a-picturebox?answertab=active#tab-top) (already mentioned elsewhere :). You custom control should update and store its new position, so the main procedure can retrieve this reference when needed.

Comment: @ZorgoZ This is the control i use https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774101/848968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MouseMove` event is called when you hover mouse on the control. If you want to check whether control is moved then please use `LocationChanged` event.

Comment: You can also rely on `Move` event.

Comment: Thanks. `LocationChanged`  Of the custom control ,right?

Comment: Yes. you can override "LocationChanged" event  of custom control.