# how make label move inside panel bounds

Tags: c#, winforms

i tried this code but when i drag and move label inside panel is normal but when i drag to edge bound of panel it disappear i want it to stop on panel bound is there a way for that?

```
private void lbl29_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void lbl29_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lbl29.Left = e.X + lbl29.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        lbl29.Top = e.Y + lbl29.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to calculate the e.g. maximum x position, ie panel.width- label.width and then assign the x = math.min(max, x)

Comment: [Don't move the Labels outside a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317811/7444103) (the same for a Panel, of course.)

Comment: Dear Jimi it worked but the label must be outside panel in start form but when i put the label inside panel in the design it take other position it start from middle i cant go up or right  like it take down right panel only small Square and be invisible down panel

Comment: and i want the label be inside panel in start the form

Comment: `LabelNewLocation.X = (LabelNewLocation.X < pnl1.Left) ? pnl1.Left : LabelNewLocation.X;
                LabelNewLocation.Y = (LabelNewLocation.Y < pnl1.Top) ? pnl1.Top : LabelNewLocation.Y;
                LabelNewLocation.X = (LabelNewLocation.X + label.Width > pnl1.Right) ? label.Left : LabelNewLocation.X;
                LabelNewLocation.Y = (LabelNewLocation.Y + label.Height > pnl1.Bottom) ? label.Top : LabelNewLocation.Y;
                label.Location = LabelNewLocation;`

Comment: this what i tried but i think it not reading pnl1 i just read every panel that why it take random position i put the label in pnl2  without change code it have same position when move label small square down right

Comment: Dear @Jimi Do You know how?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you have a Label that should move freely, except when it's dragged inside the bounds of a specific control (a Panel). When the Label enters this control, it cannot be dragged outside anymore. If this is what you're trying to do, the code you saw in the question I linked needs just a couple of adjustments. Otherwise, maybe post an image that can explain what it is.

Comment: Dear @Jimi When i put the label in panel on design mode and run program then i move label it not free on all of panel bound it just move small square in panel but when i put the label out side panel and run program and move the label it automaticly take me to panel position and i move all of panel bounds but that not what i want i want to run program while label inside panel in design mode

Answer (score 0):

You can try these: 
`Controls.SetChildIndex(lbl29, 0);` or 
`Controls.SetChildIndex(panel1, 1);` or 
`lbl29.BringToFront();` or 
`panel1.SendToBack();`
But `Controls.SetChildIndex(lbl29, 0);` and `Controls.SetChildIndex(panel1, 1);` are more useful.