# Location limit with the size of the form

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I have being wondering how to set a limit to a location using the size of the form.

```
private Point MouseDownLocation;

private void labelControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }
}

private void labelControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        labelControl1.Left = e.X + labelControl1.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        labelControl1.Top = e.Y + labelControl1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

This is the code I have been using. Can someone can help. Any code can be useful I just want some examples of how to do it.

Comment: [Don't move the Labels outside a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317811/7444103) (of course you can use the Bounds of any other Control as reference, or just a Rectangle).

Comment: Thank you it work well