# c# .NET 6 Windows Form App limiting the movement of a picturebox within a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

Currently I'm trying to implement a form that contains a picturebox within a panel, in this I currently have the functionality to zoom in/out on the imagebox and drag it around by manipulating the imagebox.Size and imagebox.Location properties. I’m struggling with implementing checks that prevent you from just dragging the image outside of the panel box (and such becoming unreachable once unclicked). I’m allowing for the image to be dragged outside so that a minimum of 20 pixels in height or width are showing at any point, any further and I trigger a mouseup event, preventing you from dragging it out any further. (I also readjust the position by a few units to ensure that it doesn’t get stuck). I effectively want a pan and zoom feature using the mousedown and mousescroll events. Also sorry if a solution exists already, i could not find anything specific to what i want :)

edit: Thank you for the suggested optimizations, frankly I don’t fully understand how event args work (the bulk of my c# education was in console apps exclusively)

So far, my solution works perfectly for the left and top borders of the panel however I am struggling to implement the right and bottom sides of the panel with the position of the drop event changing depending on the zoom level of the image and I cannot for the life of me understand why, see code below:

```cs
private void MapMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dragging && sender is Control control)
    {
        label5.Text = e.X + ", " + e.Y;
        //adjust the translations based on the recorded MousePos values
        control.Top = e.Y + control.Top - lastMousePos.Y;
        control.Left = e.X + control.Left - lastMousePos.X;
        //Top Border boundry 
        //allows for all of the image bar the last 20 pixels in its height from exiting the panel
        if (control.Top < 20 - MapBox.Height) 
        {
            control.Top = 23 - MapBox.Height;
            //trigger mouseup event to stop image movement
            Dragging = false; //as per suggestions :)
        }
        //Left Border boundry
        if (control.Left < 20 - MapBox.Width)
        {
            control.Left = 23 - MapBox.Width;
            Dragging = false;
        }


        // Right Border boundary
        if (control.Left > MapBox.Width - 20)
        {
            control.Left = MapBox.Width - 23;
            Dragging = false;
        }

        // Bottom Border boundary
        if (control.Top > MapBox.Height - 20)
        {
            control.Top = MapBox.Height - 23;
            Dragging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

as i said this code works perfectly fine and as expected with the default picturebox size, however when i resize the picturebox using the following function, it no longer stops the image at the expected location.

```cs
private void MapMouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        if (MapBox.Width + 50 < 1500) 
        {
            ZoomLevel += 1; //at the moment this does nothing, was toying with using this to counteract the offset that zooming made to the unclick event position but have had no luck yet
            MapBox.Width += 50;
            MapBox.Height += 50;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (MapBox.Width - 50 > 300)
        {
            ZoomLevel -= 1;
            MapBox.Width -= 50;
            MapBox.Height -= 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies if this is spaghetti code I’m reasonably inexperienced with c# :)

Comment: Why are you passing in a `new MouseEventArgs` into every call to `MapMouseWheel`? The `.Delta` value will always be `0`...

Comment: Isn't `control` the same thing as `MapBox`? Isn't `MapMouseUp` just setting `Dragging = false;`? So why not just set  `Dragging = false;` instead of calling `MapMouseUp`?

Comment: still looking for an exact solution however i found something that will do if i cannot find a better solution (ie maintain a specified % of the image as a minimum), here is what i found:
```
                if (control.Top > MapHolder.Height - MapBox.Height * 0.05)
                {
                    control.Top = (int)(MapHolder.Height - MapBox.Height * 0.05) - 3;
                    MapMouseUp(MapBox, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```
this works however depeding on the zoom of the image more or less min % of the image will be displayed

Comment: When your code moves the control, that also changes the reported mouse position for the next event since it is relative to the upper left corner of the control.  So lastMousePos is no longer accurate.

Comment: [How to limit the movement of Controls inside the bounds of another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53317811/7444103)